# Can't filter text or comments from all nodes by name

Tags: xpath

I know that XPath includes special functions like   `text()` or `comment()`, but how to filter this values from all the nodes:
$x('//node()[name()="p"]')

```
$x('//node()[name()="text" or name()="comment"]')
$x('//node()[name()="#text" or name()="#comment"]')
```

but this xpath works well

`$x('//node()[name()="span" or name()="p"]')`

maybe **text** and **comment** are some defected node types without `name` or `local-name` values? But chrome console shows that this values exist

[image]

Comment: Please include code as text in a `code` section and not as image.

Comment: it not depends on my particular code. try it on this page in console `$x('//node()[name()="span" or name()="p"]')`

Comment: I'm not 100% sure what you're asking, but if you want to select comments you can use `//comment()` or `//node()[self::comment()]` (same with text nodes: `//text()` or `//node()[self::text()]` (or `//text()[normalize-space()]` to ignore whitespace only text nodes)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To select a `comment()` node or `text()` node, try:

```
//node()[self::text() or self::comment()]
```

Comment: it's all because XPath is so `self`ish

Comment: yes, you did, i've edited my comment. but what else I can do here) ?